# How to stop element moving when opening developer tools

Tags: javascript, html, css

So this has been bugging me for a while now. Lets say your building a site and have various elements with z-index values. When you open developer tools or firebug depending on which browser you are using it seems to shift the elements rather than the page as a whole up.

Is this a fallback of material design over flat design or am I just missing something. It feels like something isn't right. I see the same issue across many sites and come across it myself. Just wondering if theres some css or js trick im missing to hold things in place.

Its worth adding that this is only a vertical issue so I don't believe a media query would resolve that as height isnt a factor. I also tried fixing the page body to a min-height value but this also wasnt the case. It's only the z-indexed value items that are moving.

Perhaps I need to fix the min-height of the affected individual element? but this seems a bit long if i need to do this each time

Any info on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you have `fixed` positioned elements on your page, they will naturally update their positions since opening the developer tools window reduces the viewport height or width and since they are positioned in respect to that, they are going to reposition themselves according to new sizes.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia is right.

Comment: But if you still want to fix this issue you can set a css media query and give a fix height to html, body element when viewport height is less than 650px and width is greater than 991px for desktop screens. You can adjust the size as you want. Thanks

Comment: in addition to @abhishekkannojia's answer, you can move the developer tools to the right of the screen or in a new window. this will not longer cause this visual issues

Comment: @MihaiT Absolutely right ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys first of all thanks for pitching in. Although I appreciate all your responses, they didn't really work in the way that I wanted to. Last night I id some digging and thought to myself there must be a better way to do this.

Perphaps I didn't explain enough, what I was actually trying to do was place a gradient over a background image of an element and then use the :before selector on the same element and use a z-index value. This caused a monumental ballache as varying on viewport the gradient would either not be a sufficient height OR over stretch.

Going back to my original thought I began pondering to myself thinking there MUST be a way to sit this flush with a lot less hassle. After some digging BOOM! I realised that you could actually combine the background image and gradient attributes within the same element, problem solved.

Here is the class i setup:

```
.site-header {
  min-height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#1d9bc8,#37e1d7, transparent), url("../img/herobg.jpg") no-repeat center; 
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using vh, try to set it into px.